# parameter NDSolve

Tags: functions, differential-equations

the question I need to solve is:

```
t x'[t] == -x[t] + y[t],  
t y'[t] == -5 t^2/x[t]^2 + x[t] - y[t],       
x[1] == 4, x[b] == 1
```

in order to solve the coupled equations, I need 2 boundaries for `x[1]` and `y[1]`, so I can convert the question into shooting method

```
{xsoln, ysoln} = {x, y} /. ParametricNDSolve[{  t x'[t] == -x[t] + y[t], 
 t y'[t] == -5 t^2/x[t]^2 + x[t] - y[t],
x[1] == 4, y[1] == a}, {x, y}, {t, 1, b}, {a,b}]
```

for each specific value of `b`, I can find the value of `a` which satisfies `x[b]==1` manually. But if there is any possibility that I can find the value of `a` for any value of `b` instead of plugging the value of `b` and repeating the above process.

the way I am getting the value of `a` is as follows:

first I set `b=100`, then I plot `xsoln[a][100]`, then I can locate the region of `a` which satisfies `x[100]==1`, so I use `findroot` to find the exact value of `a`.

I naively set `f[b_?NumericQ]:=a/.FindRoot[xsoln[a][b]==1,{a,0}]`, so for any `b`, I have the value of `a`. But `xsol[a][b]` is not well behaved. I can not set `FindRoot` at `a` around `0`, the starting point differs for different `b`, which can only be seted  by plotting the profile and detect the starting point.

my another idea is by adding `WhenEvent` into `NDSolve`, which is like `WhenEvent[xsoln[a][b] does not equal to 1, change the value of a, and do the calculation again]`

Thanks folks